# How to save a selected item from a picklist, a date to the same object, then the selected date and item should not be available, all in in LWC/Apex?

Tags: javascript, object, salesforce, apex, lwc

I'm trying to create a Salesfroce lightning reservation app.
In that app the selected User can select an item ('desk') from a picklist, then pick a date from a datepicker.
When a user clicks on the save button it should save (I think on an object `Reservation__c`) in the back end, and also make it **unavalaible** to other users to select the **same item on that same date**.

I couldn't find out how to save to the `Reservation__c` object the User's name (From `User` object) as well as the selected item from the picklist (`Desk__c.Desk__c`) and the Date (from a datepicker), and then how compare them thus the selected item can not be selected on same date?

[image]

Below see my code: HTML, JS, Apex

HTML

```
<template>
<div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
    </lightning-card><br />
    <lightning-card title="Desk picker" icon-name="standard:lightning_component">
        <template if:true={deskValues.data}>
            <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                <lightning-combobox 
                    name="Desk"     
                    label="Desk" 
                    value={selectedDesk} 
                    placeholder="Select a desk"
                    options={deskValues.data.values} 
                    onchange={handleChange} 
                    required>
                </lightning-combobox>
                <p>Selected desk is: <b>{selectedDesk}</b></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    </lightning-card><br />
    <lightning-card title="User picker" icon-name="standard:lightning_component">
        <template if:true={userOptionList}>
            <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
                <lightning-combobox 
                    name="User" 
                    label="User" 
                    value={selectedUser} 
                    placeholder="Select a profile"
                    options={userOptionList} 
                    onchange={handleUserChange} 
                    required>
                </lightning-combobox>
                <p>Selected user is: <b>{selectedUser}</b></p>
            </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
    <br />
    <lightning-card title="Date picker" icon-name="standard:lightning_component">
        <div class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
            <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Input Date Example</h1>
            <div>
                <lightning-input 
                    name="date" 
                    label="Enter a date" 
                    value={selectedDate} 
                    type="date"
                    onchange={handleDateChange} 
                    required>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    <br />
    <h1 class="slds-align_absolute-center">When you are done, please hit the save button.</h1>
    <br />
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Room__c" onsubmit={firesubmit}>
        <lightning-button 
            label="Save" 
            variant="brand" 
            class="slds-align_absolute-center" 
            type="submit"
            onclick={handleSave}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    <br />
    <lightning-button 
        onclick={handleConfirm} 
        label="Confirm"
        class="slds-align_absolute-center">
    </lightning-button>
</div>
```

JS

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import LightningConfirm from "lightning/confirm"
import DESK__FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Desk__c.Desk__c';
import getUsers from '@salesforce/apex/PickListHelper.getUsers';
import RESERVATION from '@salesforce/schema/Reservation__c';

export default class DeskList extends LightningElement {
//  selectedValue;
 selectedDesk;
 userOptionList;
 selectedUser;
 selectedDate;
 

 /* retrieve picklist values from Room's Desk filed */
 @wire(getPicklistValues, {
     recordTypeId: '0127Q000000ulSc',
     fieldApiName: DESK__FIELD
    }) deskValues;
    
    
    /* wiring an apex method to a function, where tempArray = MAP */
    @wire(getUsers)
    retrieveProfiles({error, data}) {
        let tempArray = [];
        if (data) {
            for (let key in data) {
                /* prepare options with label and value, where key = Id */
                tempArray.push({label:data[key], value:data[key] + ': ' + key } );
            }
            this.userOptionList = tempArray;
        }
        else if(error) {
        }
    }

    /*Handle selected Desk */
    handleChange(event) {
        this.selectedDesk = event.target.value;
    }

    /* displaying selected user */
    handleUserChange(event) {
        this.selectedUser = event.target.value;
        console.log("hello", this.selectedUser );
    }

    /* displaying selected date */
    handleDateChange(event) {
        this.selectedDate = event.target.value;
        console.log("hello", this.selectedDate );
    }


    handleSave (event) {
        const myfield = event.detail.fields;
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }

    async handleConfirm() {
      const result = await LightningConfirm.open({
            message: 'Please confirm!',
            variant: 'headerless',
            label: 'this is the aria-label value',
            // setting theme would have no effect
        });
    }
}
```

Apex ('PickListHelper': gets the User's FirstName and email address)

```
public with sharing class PickListHelper {
   
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Map<String, String> getUsers(){
        Map<String, String> userMap = new Map<String, String>();
        for(User userObj: [SELECT FirstName, Email FROM User WHERE Username LIKE '%@%.%']){
            userMap.put(userObj.Email, userObj.FirstName);
        }
        return userMap;
    }
}
```

I am quite a beginner, I am very grateful for any help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've build something similar recently.

You can import createRecord, that will allow you to set fields and create the record.

```
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
```

You can then create an object for the fields you want to save and set them, then save the record:

```
const fields = {};
fields['User__c'] = Id;
fields['Date__c'] = this.deskslot.slotDate;
fields['TableNo__c'] = this.deskNo;

const recordInput = { apiName: 'Desk_Booking__c', fields };
createRecord(recordInput)
        .then(() => {
           
           this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Success',
                    message: 'Desk reserved',
                    variant: 'success',
              }),
           );
           this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('deleteslot'));
        })
        .catch(error => {
           this.dispatchEvent(
              new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Error creating record',
                    message: error.body.message,
                    variant: 'error',
              }),
        );
  });
```

The createRecord call returns a promise, you can then show a success message as I have above and catch any errors.

For checking if a record exists I had to create an apex class with an @AuraEnable flag on a function because the query was too complex to handle with js.  That function does the soql query and returns a record if it exists.
a pseudo example of that class :

```
public with sharing class DeskBookingController {
  public DeskBookingController() {

  }

@AuraEnabled
  public static bool findDeskBooking(Date dateToCheck, 
                string userId, string desk) {

     int slot = [ SELECT count() from FROM Desk_Booking__c WHERE Date__c   =datetoCheck and UserId__c = userId and deskID__c = desk];

    if (slot > 0 ){
       return true;
    }else{
      return false;}
  }
}
```

to call this from your component you need to import it

```
import findDeskBookings from '@salesforce/apex/DeskBookingController.findDeskBooking';
```

then call it like this:

```
findDeskBookings({ dateToCheck: this.currentDate, userId: this.userid, desk: deskId })
```

Hope this helps.